# how to increase the speed of my website

Tags: magento2, pagespeed

I checked my website at google speed :

> https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=fr&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mdsoft-test.com%2FSiteSajaddav2%2FSiteSajjada%2Fhome-demo-01&tab=desktop

and i found that it is slow so how to speed my website thanks in advance

Comment: Hey your question is not clear to us do you want to know how to speed up your site?

Comment: it'was found that my website is too slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello there are many ways to optimise your magento website:

1. **Enable Flat Categories and Products:** One of the problems identified in the slowdown of Magento 2 sites had been the read speed of the database. If your Magento 2 store has a wide range of products, you are likely to face this problem more. To increase the read speed of your database, you should enable flat categories and products. By doing this, you can minimize the number of database joins done when it shows the products. It leads to the reduction of MySQL query complexity and your site’s performance is improved.
2. **Merge CSS and JS Files:** CSS and JS files are used to make your frontend look attractive but at the same time adversely affect the speed of your site. If you are using Magento 2, fortunately you have a way to tackle this without compromising the fancy display of your site. You can merge JS and CSS files to increase the speed of your Magento 2 site. To change the settings, go to backend and select ‘configuration’ from the ‘stores’ icon, and further open the ‘developer’ tab from the ‘ADVANCED’ header. Here, you need to change the JavaScript settings to ‘Yes’ for ‘Merge JavaScript files’ and ‘Minify JavaScript files’. Similarly, go to CSS settings and opt ‘Yes’ for ‘Merge CSS files’ and ‘Minify CSS files’.
3. **Use Full Page Cache:**  The power of full page caching lies in its ability to store the full page output in the cache. This decreases the server load for when consequent pages are loading.
4. **Image Optimization:** n ecommerce store is full of images and banners for obvious reasons. To make sure that the images aren’t affecting your site’s performance, optimize them accordingly. The images that appear on the main site should be compressed for less data usage and easy page loads. While the product images should be in JPEG format, PNG and SVG format is recommended for logo and layout of your Magento 2 site.
5. **Reduce Server Response Time**
6. **Choose the right Content Delivery Network**
7. **Magento Updates**

   So these are some points by which you can speedup your site for more information regarding the same you can use go through following [link.](https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/magento-2-performance-optimization/)

Answer (score 3):

just check your inspect element on your browser when load the page and go the network tab and see column to get you know what files that have big size and cause your website be slow.

try to follow the google page insight recomendation :

- you too load many fonts file on your website (there are 6 fonts), please filter only font that you used.
- minify your css and js file that you used.
- merge your css and js file you can do this on the backend your website.
- optimize your image since I get .png file that have 1mb size (that size is too big for just one image)
- for slider image you can use jpg or jpeg format that have more little size instead using png file.
- enable gzip compression on your apache server, by follow this [article](https://gtmetrix.com/enable-gzip-compression.html)

the most crutial things I think on the image and the fonts, js and css file. > 10 mb for load one page I thinks it's very not efficient.

Hope this helps

Comment: what do you mean bu merge your css and js how do do that exactly please ?

Comment: in the backend your website, go to menu `system->configuration`, select `advanced` tab and then on the right side you will see section `javascript settings` and `css settings`, expand and then you will see option `Merge Javascript files` and `Merge Css files` set them to `Yes`

Answer (score 0):

1. First I see in your slider, the images are so big and not optimized `1.80 Mo` and so on, it's not good.
2. It depends to your server configuration.
3. Did you enabled the **cache** ?
4. You can also merge **css**, **js** (admin config)
5. Optimized custom code, check if you have optimized your custom **code**, exemple many loads, not optimized collections **select**, **filters** etc... **foreach** etc... .

Comment: yes the cache is enabled