# Magento 2 How to do gzip compression magento 2

Tags: magento2, pagespeed

I want to speed up my website i followed those steps [how to increase the speed of my website](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246635/how-to-increase-the-speed-of-my-website/246642#246642) but still i have this :[image]

Also i did not find the .htaccess to add a code to enable the gzip so how to do that and how to make my website faster ?! I need your help pleaase

Comment: Pls check here https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/magento-2-performance-optimization/

Comment: i did see this article but the question is where to find the . htaccess